# Irreducible polynomial of degree $2$ over a finite field of characteristic $2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Let $F$ be a finite field of characteristic $2$. I need to find an irreducible polynomial of degree $2$ over $F$.

To that effect, I was given the following hint: "Find a polynomial $f$ and an element $a \in F$ such that $f(x) = f(x+a)$".

I thought about, perhaps letting $a = 2$. Then, if I let $f(x) = bx^{2} + cx + d$, I have that $f(x+2) = b(x+2)^{2}+c(x+2) + d = bx^{2} + 2b\cdot2 + cx + 2x+d = bx^{2} + 0 + cx + d = bx^{2}+cx + d = f(x),$

but I don't see how this gives me an irreducible polynomial of degree $2$.

Could somebody please help me figure this out? Thank you! :)

Comment: f(x)=x^2+x+1 we have that f(x)=f(x+1)

Comment: @SeanNemetz is your $f$ irreducible in this $F$?

Comment: yea, it doesn't have a root

Comment: @SeanNemetz for the rationals, we have the rational root test. In a finite field of characteristic $2$, how do you test whether a polynomial has a root?

Comment: $x^2+x+1$ is the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_3$ and $\mathbf{F}_2(\zeta_3 ) = \mathbf{F}_4$. Then $f(x+2) = f(x)$ is supposed to be obvious in characteristic $2$..

Comment: @reuns we have not gotten to Galois theory yet

Comment: If you let $x_0$ be a root of $f$, what does $f(x_0)=f(x_0+1)$ tell you?

Comment: @SeanNemetz that $x_{0}+1$ must also be a root of $f$?

Comment: Ok, so $f(x)=x^2+x+1=(x-x_0)(x-(x_0+1))$

Comment: @SeanNemetz but then, it's not irreducible. So, $x_{0}$ cannot be a root.

Comment: @SeanNemetz I see what you did there, but what does Lubin's answer have to do with it? Then I'll go away, I promise.

Comment: We know that $x^2+x \not = x^2+x+1$

Comment: @SeanNemetz It seems like you're assuming $F = \mathbb{F}_2$, which is not necessarily the case.  What if $F = \mathbb{F}_4$?  This also has characteristic $2$, but $x^2 + x + 1$ has a root in $\mathbb{F}_4$.

Comment: @Quasicoherent then what is the polynomial I want here? I still don't really understand what it is it from Lubin's answer below. Last night when I thought it was $x^{2}+x+1$, I was able to convince myself. But now, I'm lost as ever. I wish he had explained his last comment in more detail, but I felt bad asking so many follow up questions.

Comment: @Quasicoherent Say it's $x^2+x+a$. What conditions do we place on $a$?

Comment: @ALannister Well, if $a$ is in the image of Lubin's map $g$, then $z^2 + z = a$ for some $z \in F$.  But then $z$ is a solution to $z^2 + z - a = 0$, so the polynomial $x^2 + x - a$ has a root, hence is reducible.  Does that show you what condition we must place on $a$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let your field of characteristic two be $F$, and consider the mapping $g:F\to F$, by $z\mapsto z^2+z$. Notice that it’s additive, that is $g(a+b)=g(a)+g(b)$. Do you know a little group theory? What’s the kernel of this homomorphism? Finiteness of $F$ tells you that $g$ is not onto. Does that help?

Comment: No, $z^2+z=z(z+1)$.

Comment: There was a second part to the hint I mentioned above. It said to use a similar argument to what follows: "Observe that $a^{2} = (-a)^{2}$ for any $a \in F$. If $char(F) \neq 2$, we have $2a \neq 0$ (because $2$ is a unit of $F$), hence $a \neq -a$. This implies that the map $a \mapsto a^{2}$ is not surjective on $F$ and, consequently, the set of squares of elements of $F$ is a proper subset of $F$. If $b$ is not a square then the polynomial $x^{2}-b$ has no roots in $F$".

Comment: you're doing something similar, right? But of course, since $char(F) = 2$, $a = -a$. So, we need a different way to show that $a \mapsto a^{2}$ is not surjective.

Comment: Actually, $a\mapsto a^2$ *is* surjective. But $a\mapsto a^2+a$ is *not* surjective when $F$ is finite.

Comment: how does the kernel come into play? Does that help me figure out what the polynomial is?

Comment: The order of the kernel is also the index of the image (“range”). Since the kernel has two elements, half of $F$ is image, half is not image. In other words, the mapping is not surjective. Once you know nonsurjectivity, you have your quadratic polynomial without roots.

Comment: I still haven't figured it out. Last night, I thought I had convinced myself it was $x^2+x+1$ but I was wrong. If you could explain your last comment in more detail, I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: Awright, I’ll give it to you. Nonsurjectivity means that there is $w\in F$ that is not of the form $z^2+z$, no matter what $z$ you look at in $F$. So your irreducible polynomial is $X^2+X-w$. Has no roots in $F$, right? Therefore irreducible (since of degree two), right?

Comment: thank you! I've finally got it!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't use $a=2$, because in a field of characteristic 2, that means $a=0$ and you're back to square one.

Once you've found your $f$ and $a$, you can let $g(x) = f(x) + f(x+a) + 1$. Since $f(x) = f(x+a)$ (and $F$ chas characteristic 2), it follows that $g(x)=1$ for all $x$.

Comment: how does $g$ have degree $2$?

Comment: Good point, I missed that bit. You may need $f$ to be cubic.